# Querying sub-sub table in Supabase / Grandchild relationship in JOIN QUERY

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database, postgrest

Given the following schema:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE organization (
   org_name text  NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (org_name)
);

CREATE TABLE teams (
   org_name text NOT NULL,
   team_name text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (org_name, team_name),
   FOREIGN KEY (org_name)
      REFERENCES organization (org_name)
);

CREATE TABLE projects (
   org_name text NOT NULL,
   team_name text NOT NULL,
   project_name text NOT NULL,
   products jsonb,
   PRIMARY KEY (org_name, team_name, project_name),
   FOREIGN KEY (org_name)
      REFERENCES organization (org_name),
   FOREIGN KEY (org_name, team_name)
      REFERENCES teams (org_name, team_name)
);
```

I want to query the `teams` table but also return the `products` from the `projects` table. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For single relationships set, then you can do the following (assuming a top-bottom relationship as:

`organization -> teams` and `teams -> projects`

```js
const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY);
const { data: ret, error } = await supabase
  .from('organization')
  .select(`*, 
           teams(*,
                 projects(products)
                )
          `);
console.log(JSON.stringify(ret));
```

In this case, it would not be possible and you would get the following error:

> Could not embed because more than one relationship was found for 'organization' and 'teams'

In this case, you can pick the relationship when calling supabase with either:
`teams!projects` or `teams!teams_org_name_fkey`. The former is preferred for most cases.

```js
const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY);
const { data: ret, error } = await supabase
  .from('organization')
  .select(`*, 
          teams!projects(*,
                        projects(products)
                        )
         `);
```

### Output:

> [{"org_name":"Contoso","teams":[{"org_name":"Contoso","team_name":"Contoso Café","projects":[{"products":{"Dairy":"latte","coffee":["french press","expresso","cold brew"]}}]}]}]