# Request columns for multiple tables using supabasejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, supabase

So supabase allows for two tables pretty simply.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from('table1')
 .select('table1.thing1, table1.thing2, table2(table2.thing2, table2.thing3)')
.console.log(data)
```

What I am trying to do is access a 3rd table to get information from table2 but I need table 1 to have the data.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from('table1')
 .select('table1.thing1, table2.thing2, table2(table2.thing2, table2.thing3), table3(table3.thing2, table3.thing2)')
console.log(data)
```

I would expect this to give me a data across all 3 but I just get a null returned.

Comment: I have read this and it doens't seem to answer but I may need to add another 'joining table'. Hoping I don't have to as it seems a little overly repetitive.

Comment: Are there relationships between these tables? If there are, then you can check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75389023/2188186

Comment: Thanks @Mansueli I ended up just making a view. It works ‍♀️ but this is definitely awesome to know for the future!

Answer (score 0):

With @supabase if you want to connect more than one table via supabasejs query your best bet is to just make a view. I hope this helps someone else out there!