# supabase eq not filtering rows by join table association (querying with serverSupabaseClient)

Tags: node.js, supabase

I am trying to only fetch the rows for `letters` that are associated with user `80cdd279-1b2b-4df4-995c-a309f9cfd28a`, but all the rows of `letters` are being returned.

Here is the query I am using. It is returning all the `letters` despite the `eq`. And the data is the same when I remove the `eq` clause.

```
client.from('letters')
  .select('*, users_letters(*)')
  .eq(`users_letters.users_id`, '80cdd279-1b2b-4df4-995c-a309f9cfd28a')
```

If I change the select to `.select('*, users_letters!inner(*)')` I don't get any rows returned.

users_letters (join table)

| id (int 8, pk) | users_id (uuid, fk) | letters_id (int8, fk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80cdd279-1b2b-4df4-995c-a309f9cfd28a | 2 |
| 2 | 80cdd279-1b2b-4df4-995c-a309f9cfd28a | 3 |
| 3 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | 2 |

letters

| id (int8, pk) | text (text) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "hello" |
| 2 | "goodbye" |
| 3 | "maybe" |

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Updated to show actual data types used and primary keys (pk) and foreign keys (fk).

Comment: is the `users_id` int?  
You can also check some examples of [join queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389022/querying-sub-sub-table-in-supabase-grandchild-relationship-in-join-query/75389023#75389023).

Comment: @Mansueli the users_id in my code is actually a uuid. I've been playing with joins, but I'll check out those examples to see if I can get something working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question/share a [mcve] here?  I am unable to reproduce it with the data above. But I'll be glad to figure this out with you.

Comment: @Mansueli updated with actual data types and keys. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, did u found an answer to this ?