# Querying reverse related fields in supabase

Tags: reactjs, supabase

Let's be straight forward.

Querying related fields in supabase is pretty easy

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select(`
    name,
    cities (
      name
    )
  `)
```

The above code fetches all the countries and also the name of all cities related by a foreign key.
If we have a table created like this:

```
create table
  countries (id int8 primary key, name text);

create table
  cities (
    id         int8 primary key,
    country_id int8 not null references countries,
    name       text
  );
```

The response of this query will be

```
[
    {
      "name": "Germany",
      "cities": [
        {
          "name": "Munich"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Indonesia",
      "cities": [
        {
          "name": "Bali"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

But what I want to achieve is:
I want to fetch all the cities name like

```
 await supabase.from("cities").select()
```

The response would be something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "City name",
    country_id: "Country id",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "City name 2",
    country_id: "Country id 2",
  },
]
```

But what I want to achieve is:

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "City name",
    country: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Country name 1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "City name 2",
    country: {
      id: 2,
      name: "Country name 2",
    },
  },
];
```

I might have to make changes on the way I have created the table or relations. I have created tables and relations just the normal way.

Can somebody help me with this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying sub-sub table in Supabase / Grandchild relationship in JOIN QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389022/querying-sub-sub-table-in-supabase-grandchild-relationship-in-join-query)

Answer (score 0):

After digging more into supabase docs, I think I found the solution.

The supabase syntax for this scenario would be just

```
await supabase.from("cities").select("*,countries(*)")
```

This will select all the `cities` as well as the related field `countries` will be included in the response.